# ¿Cómo contar elementos de una variable tipo Enum en C#?

Tags: c#, enum

Una variable de tipo `Enum` puede tener ninguno o muchos elementos de acuerdo a la definición del enumerable, al final lo que deseo es contar el número de elementos incluidos en esa variable.

Este es el `Enum`:

```
[Flags]
enum WeekDays
{
    None = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 1 << 1,
    Wednesday = 1 << 2,
    Thursday = 1 << 3,
    All = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday
}
```

Esta es la clase donde se declara una propiedad de tipo `WeekDays`:

```
class Temp
{
    public WeekDays SomeWeekDays { get; set; }
}
```

Así asigno elementos del enumerador a la variable:

```
Temp temp = new Temp();
temp.SomeWeekDays = WeekDays.Monday | WeekDays.Tuesday;
```

Al final lo que requiero es obtener un `2` al intentar contar los elementos de `temp.SomeWeekDays`, ¿existe alguna manera de poder hacerlo?

Como nota final, existe el método `Enum.GetValues` pero este no me funciona porque me va a contar todos los elementos del enumerador, no de la variable:

```
var elements = Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDays));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atendiendo a que cuando aplicas el **método** **ToString** a la variable de tipo enumeración este te devuelve un **string** con todos los elementos separados por coma puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var Total = temp.SomeWeekDays.ToString().Split(',').Count();
```

Usamos la **función** **Split** para separar la cadena por la **','** y este **método Split** nos devolverá un arreglo al que le aplicamos la **función** **Count**, devolviéndose de esta forma el total de elementos que buscas.

Para usar la **función** **Count** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```